# Microservice Authentication and Authorization Using API Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I have three micro services user-service , order-service and product-service. user-service has users' related api's like login , register etc. Order-service has  order the product and get product information from product-service . So, micro service works like user-service , 
and order-service ---->>used--->> product-service. Now i want to make use of zuul api gateway and config zuul filter in that.Like that

```
public class PreFilter extends ZuulFilter {

  @Override
  public Object run() {
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
   // Here first i get token from header and then 
   // call to auth-server and then validate token if it is ok then go forword if  
   // token is not valid then thow exception unauthentication 
  }
}
```

Now request for user works as
  api gateway --->> user service

request for order

api gateway -->> order-service --->> product-service

Now request for order works as 
    Api gateway --->> auth server (validate token) ---- if token validate request goes to order service ----->>>> order service ------->> product service.
    My Question, is that if I validate token in api gateway and I can access the order service directly, then how can I stop such request which are not coming from through api gateway and didn't want validate token in order-service and product service ?. 
   I want one such entry point and want to validate token for order and product api's if anyone want to access order-service api's without valid token then order-service or product service does not work for them. Please help me to understand, how I could design my project structure.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Are you asking how to avoid direct access to your microservice?

Comment: @FabioManzano Yes ,  i want direct acceess of microservice . user-service and order-service access through zuul api gateway and product-service either access by api-gateway or order-service

Comment: It depends on the deployment strategy you're going to follow. You should only expose the API Gateway to the outside world, or whatever you need.

Comment: @FabioManzano yes u r right , i am exposing only api gateway to the world but is is there any way to secure order-service and product service and these services are not access directly

Comment: Well, deployment and environment configuration is key. Besides this, you told that you're using some kind of token-based authentication, right?

Comment: @FabioManzano i m using token base auth and get this token in zuul filter in api gat gateway server then call to auth server for authentication now if token correct and valid then request send to order-service and order-service call product service